# checkbox not selected when clicking on checkbox using material ui in React js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In react i am using material ui DataGrid  and with checkboxSelection api but when i select checkbox it will not select but when I click on any other row  it selects the checkbox. I used  `disableClickEventBubbling: true` for disabling the `<select>` when clicking row but **clicking checkbox itself is still not working**

```
    const columns = [
  { field: '"id', headerName: 'id', width: 150 ,
  disableClickEventBubbling: true,

},


<DataGrid rows={rows}
      columns={columns}
      pageSize={10}
      paginationMode='server'
     
      showColumnRightBorder
       hideFooterPagination
       showToolbar
       autoHeight
       onSelectionChange={({rowIds}) => setSelectedRecords(rowIds)}
       checkboxSelection
       />
```

Comment: If you remove the onSelectionChange, it doesn't have the expected behavior ?

Comment: How is the ```DataGrid``` implemented?

Comment: no removing onSelectionChange does not work